# Rails filter product listing based on attribute in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails newbie here. This specific question has probably been asked before, if not here then on some other site, but after looking around a lot I wasn't able to find anything helpful because I lack the terminology to describe what I want to accomplish. I'm sorry if it comes across as trivial.

Basically I have a freshly created Rails project with a scaffold `Item` (generated by `rails g scaffold Item [...attributes...]`) and I want to create an additional page, similar to the index page, but instead of displaying all of the items I want the items to be filtered. So for the index page the part in the controller file looks like this

```
def index
 @items = Item.all
end
```

and I want to know how to, instead, have some sort of controller for my other page (call it `index2`) that uses some find-like method only grabs the `Items` that have a certain attribute, e.g. are `"red"` in `color`:

```
def index2
  @items = Item.find(color: "red") #all items that have red as their color attribute
end                                #are assigned to @items
```

How can I do this? And where can I find more manipulations (other than `all()`, `first`, `second`, ...) like this? Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an action to your ItemsController

```
def red_items
  @items = Item.where(color: "red")
end
```

you can use where for all the filters

You will have to add a view called `red_items.html.erb` to `/app/views/items` for the controller to render automatically. If you want to use index template, then just render the template explicitly in your new action

```
def red_items
  @items = Item.where(color: "red")
  render :template => "index"
end
```

Here is a link to [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) where you can find all possible query methods